# Incorrect data security form - SPLIT_BUNDLE 5

Tags: split, bundle, declaration, policy

i just finished my project (business manager) and I'm facing problem with policy declaration and google reject my app.
How to fullfil data security form? , could you help me please?

-First of all, a user needs to sign up in my app (create a new account) , and the app collect his name and email and password and save all in firebase.
-The user can add his customers name , phone number, address and debt to database .

- the user can review the history of sales, purchases and fees with images took by the user.